# Carnival Shooter Puzzle

Tags: probability

**Bet:** 
Being at the carnival shooter, Randolph proposes a bet to Susan. Whoever clears $s=80$% of the board from plastic stars *first* wins. The loser pays.

$\hskip2in$[image]

**Setup:** 
The shooting board features $k$ plastic stars where each star $i$ covers $p_i$ percent of the wall: $\mathbf{p}=\langle p_1, \cdots, p_k \rangle$. At the beginning, the complete board is covered with stars: $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i=1$. The shooting judge will signal the winner as soon as $s=80$% of the board has been cleared from plastic stars.
Both have *unlimited ammo* and don't need to recharge. The shooting board for Randolph is the exact copy of the board for Susan. Stars don't overlap and each star can be shot only once.

**Randolph's strategy:** Since he has unlimited ammo and is otherwise not a good shooter, he decides to shot at the board *uniformly at random*. To formalise his random strategy, let $\mathbf{x}=\langle x_1, \cdots, x_k \rangle$ where $x_i$ is the random variable indicating whether the star $i$ has been shot ($x_i=1$) or not ($x_i=0$). Let $\hat X$ be the star that is shot in the *next* iteration. Then, 
\begin{align}
P(\hat X=i) = (1-x_i)p_i
\end{align}
*Every shot takes $1$ seconds*.

**Susan's strategy:** Susan is a much better shooter. Every shot brings down a star. She chooses the next star as follows. Let $\mathbf{x}=\langle x_1, \cdots, x_k \rangle$ where $x_i$ is the random variable indicating whether the star $i$ has been shot ($x_i=1$) or not ($x_i=0$). Let $\hat X$ be the star that is shot in the *next* iteration. Then, 
\begin{align}
P(\hat X=i) = \frac{(1-x_i)p_i}{\sum_{j=1}^k(1-x_j)p_j}
\end{align}
*Because she takes her time, every shot takes $\mathtt c$ seconds.*

**The Problem:** 
Of course, Susan cannot take too much time. Otherwise, Randolph will clear $s=80$%  faster than her. So, $\mathtt c$ is bounded above. **What is the time $\mathtt{c}_0$ that Susan can take per shot such that Susan is expected to achieve $s=80$% in exactly the same time than Randolph?**

Consequently, for every $\mathtt c > \mathtt c_0$, Randolph is expected to clear $s=80$% of the board first and wins.

Comment: In the final question, I think it needs something like "with probability $\leq 0.5$" added to it, or some similar mention of probability. Otherwise, to me, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Okay, I tried to clarify the question.